# Disabling device sensors globally from android java class

Tags: android, android-source, android-sensors

Here again with a complex and very specific case.
I am working with a custom OS based on AOSP (android 11).

I also have an app which acts as a device controller. I would like to implement a fragment with a list of switches and each switch will represent a sensor on the device such as: Accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetic, etc.

Here comes the challenge:

How can I disable a specific sensors or a group of sensors globally so neither the apps nor the OS can utilise the sensors until turned back on?

It is okay if the device should be restarted to apply the changes.

I found I way to disable sensors during build time by modifying the SensorManagerService but this won’t help as this feature is meant for the end user.

Any word of advice or hint will be helpful as I tried a lot of different ways to achieve that but without any luck.

Comment: I'd add a method to SensorManager to enable or disable sensors which can only be called by system apps. Now after that you normally need a API which tells the apps when sensors get disabled and so on. Because I assume that's not what you want to do I'd simply return fake data when apps query the sensor(s) while it's disabled. Also simply don't call events like onSensorChanged and onAccuracyChanged when the sensor is disabled.

Comment: That’s a very good idea, but I can’t find a very well written documentation on the SensorManager and how can I enable/disable the sensors as the default methods utilise a listener to do that and stops the sensor only for an app not globally.

Comment: @Top4of If you can't find a documentation you have to read the source code. You have to understand how /dev/binder and Android system services work. Here is a good documentation: https://proandroiddev.com/binders-in-android-part-1-e875daeb762f

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will take a look and if I find a solution will make a proper answer. Cheers.

Comment: @zomega Okay I managed to create my own native method and reach the native code. Now I realized that disabling the sensor with the switch won't stop it to be added again on restart. I decided to store a txt file with all disable sensors, but it seems there is no directory on the device where I can store the text file so it can be accessed on the next boot. The external storage is encrypted on reboot until first unlock and all system folders are read-only. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The SensorManager has to store the sensor states (disabled or enabled). Not your app. You could use an SQLite database and store it under /data/misc/togglesensors.db for example.

Comment: I will try tomorrow. I'm not quite sure I can access the /data/misc when the SensorManger is starting on boot but will check that.